# 8 pieces on one file in a master game at standard time control?

Tags: records, master-games

In today's (21st May 2023) game in the [Superbet Rapid and Blitz](https://chess24.com/en/watch/live-tournaments/grand-chess-tour-superbet-rapid-and-blitz-2023/1/1/5) between Maxime Vachier-Lagrave and Levon Aronian they reached a position where the c-file was fully occupied with pieces and pawns.

```
[Title "MVL vs Aronian, Superbet Rapid & Blitz 2023"]
[fen ""]
[Startply "27"]

1. d4 Nf6 2. Bf4 c5 3. e3 Qb6 4. Nc3 Qxb2 5. Nb5 Nd5 6. Rb1 Qxa2 7. Ra1 Qb2 8. Nf3 Nc6 9. Bc4 Nc3 10. Nc7+ Kd8 11. Qc1 Qxc1+ 12. Rxc1 e5 13. Nxe5 Kxc7 14. Nxf7+ Kb6 15. Nxh8 d5 16. Bd3 Be6 17. Bxh7 c4 18. Ng6 Ba3 19. Ra1 Bb2 20. Kd2 Bxa1 21. Rxa1 Ne4+ 22. Kc1 Nf6 23. Rb1+ Ka6 24. Ra1+ Kb6 25. Rb1+ Ka6 26. Ra1+ Kb6 27. Rb1+ 1/2-1/2
```

Has this ever happened in a FIDE rated master level game at standard time controls?

Comment: I am sure it has happened quite often (and most often on the c-file), I have at least one game myself with this pattern - will try to find it once I have some time.

Comment: You've asked [a very similar question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/37563) before. It has obviously happened before (e.g. Italian game). I suppose it'd be interesting to check if it's happened with other files.

Comment: @double-beep If you think it is a duplicate then you should vote to close

Comment: It's certainly not a duplicate (linked question asks for FIDE world championship games and requires symmetry). I just pointed the similarity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is today's World Championship game the first with a symmetrical position and one file completely occupied?](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/37563/is-todays-world-championship-game-the-first-with-a-symmetrical-position-and-one)